# How can I not get an error if the bot doesn't have the permission to send message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have `if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("SEND_MESSAGES")) return;` in my code but when I disable the bot's permission to **Send Messages** it gives me an error, `(node:2504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`. How could I possibly solve this issue so I won't get the error when my bot cannot send messages into a chat.

Comment: Has this Command something to do with Roles?

Answer (score 1):

Do this before the message event

**Try this:**

```
if (message.author.bot) {
 return;
} else {
 //do soemthing if user is not a bot
}
```

Comment: I tried putting that inside my `/event/client/message.js` folder but it still gives me the error.

Comment: can you specify whats the error you have i.e errorcode or error message ?

Comment: It's still sending me this error `(node:2504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use a try catch block to catch the exception and then just don't print the error.

like :

`try{
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("SEND_MESSAGES")) return;
}catch{}`

Comment: I ran into a problem with the code that you provided. It's not giving me any errors however the commands are not working. I tried putting the code inside and outside the `{}` and both didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the permission required isn't `SEND_MESSAGES`.

For example, if you are coding a `ban` command, you would also need to check if the bot has the `BAN_MEMBERS` permissions.

If it was an `add-role` command, you would have to check if the bot highest role is higher than the role it needs to assign.

Comment: But I'm checking if my bot can either send a message or not; because it give me an error `(node:2504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions` when my bot doesn't have the permission to send a mesage

Comment: @Meko what is the command you're trying to run when this error pops up ?

Comment: @Meko Could you show us where exactly you did put the permission check ?

Comment: @Meko This is your full command ? You should try to put the permission check before running every command in your main file / message event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215601/discussion-between-meko-and-tenclea).